# Manually predict from a GLS model

Tags: r

I'm trying to predict manually (since predict command doesn't works) using a GLS model averaging.
I was able to predict from the full (single) model, but unfortunatly something was wrong with the averaging, in particular on the standard error computation.
Have you any idea on what was wrong with the code?

I provide here the code with annotation on what was wrong and below the dataset:

```
library(nlme)
library(MuMIn)
options(na.action=na.fail)

# Full model
rs_sin <- gls(Snlpall ~ marg + urban + crop + npatches + siepi + guyot, 
                        correlation=corGaus(form=~x_centroide+y_centroide),data=dati1, method="ML")

# Averaged model
dredge_rs_sin <- dredge(rs_sin,rank="AICc")
avg_rs_sin <- model.avg(get.models(dredge_rs_sin, subset=delta<2))

#Newdata
MyData <- data.frame(
Intercept=1,
marg=mean(dati1$marg,na.rm=TRUE),
urban=mean(dati1$urban,na.rm=TRUE),
crop=mean(dati1$crop,na.rm=TRUE),
npatches= seq(3,59,length=50),
siepi=mean(dati1$siepi,na.rm=TRUE),
guyot=mean(dati1$guyot,na.rm=TRUE))

X <- model.matrix (~npatches+crop+guyot+marg+urban+siepi,data=MyData)

#Plot for full model -> it works
Betas <- coef(rs_sin)
FitManual <- Betas[1] + X %*% Betas
SE <- sqrt(diag((Betas[1] +X) %*% vcov(rs_sin)%*% t(X)))

plot(x=dati1$npatches,y=dati1$Snlpall,pch=16,
     xlab="",
     ylab="R") 
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual+1.96*SE,lty=3)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual-1.96*SE,lty=3)


# Plot for averaged model --> doesn't work     
Betas1 <- coef(avg_rs_sin)
FitManual1 <- Betas[1] + X %*% Betas
SE1 <- sqrt(diag((Betas[1] +X) %*% vcov(avg_rs_sin)%*% t(X))) # think there is something wrong here with the vcov matrix.

plot(x=dati1$npatches,y=dati1$Snlpall,pch=16,
     xlab="npatches",
     ylab="R") 
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual1)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual1+1.96*SE1,lty=3)
lines(x=MyData$npathes,y=FitManual1-1.96*SE1,lty=3)

dati1 <- "Snlpall   x_centroide y_centroide crop    marg    urban   npatches    guyot   siepi
8   650582,173  5065311,29  5,769653689 9,795154729 0   28  1,960020934 0
17  650780,186  5079478,53  25,19722986 13,71890437 0   28  0   302,69
14  650837,792  5080986,29  26,34250299 9,567729568 3,046477232 37  96,3649795  837,52
12  650219,122  5080711,8   8,395660557 24,13350622 0   52  6,545660511 509,33
13  651557,988  5101389,96  7,292986941 10,47537282 0,588274573 18  86,98728834 188,05
14  655830,737  5084020,78  0   25,01851151 5,185242251 27  37,06489205 1131,77
13  656885,037  5085527,09  6,239801769 15,938253   2,089378711 32  6,732789886 217,6
10  656439,59   5086246,3   1,566067089 28,25899447 2,414442568 31  20,31262478 652,75
15  657651,392  5088343,61  0   26,92627763 0   10  0   110,04
15  665088,801  5106474,71  2,344176929 9,080539984 20,04834903 16  50,55249007 295,9
19  666923,149  5105672,06  3,550300232 6,603493481 13,4842657  33  1,713945878 610,21
14  666330,463  5105218,78  8,814677781 19,04378682 2,238734061 19  22,09936244 461,42
8   663247,545  5089075,69  0   14,74065481 0   29  0   67,59
15  649285,276  5091888,15  2,044514273 16,78475343 0,56687594  29  0   231,29
21  647238,32   5086540,65  5,952167331 19,49417274 2,915539422 27  14,99881993 778,98
16  644288,69   5084165,78  1,047482846 8,869228822 5,744886625 25  0   288,87
16  643016,618  5086852,26  0   18,82747991 0,715776494 50  19,76403792 130,19
16  651591,549  5065387,62  0   19,10503177 9,14077972  29  13,88805625 955,05
17  651623,279  5067082,62  0   21,15942749 7,353140001 32  14,18706054 577,39
11  644101,088  5085295,24  2,112922262 8,341540175 10,77505968 20  7,039046512 143,35
13  656501,846  5104763,24  15,79404027 6,589650793 0   26  100 202,18
14  653489,915  5104621,42  0,427149926 8,334455888 0,981809052 35  17,56994026 401,91
10  652847,844  5101659,97  2,235819659 20,96245805 0   22  0   507,62
2   651140,976  5100582,37  0   8,49665102  0   3   94,38359412 0
14  666901,441  5123370,88  0   10,84161287 0   21  0   10,82
14  665505,438  5122295,29  2,668232966 23,09955977 0   23  0   98,18
9   661432,335  5120828,54  5,832749208 3,193257302 0,113399036 19  0   0
16  656108,474  5071049,08  0   10,05094278 0   26  0   68,57
16  665694,213  5118017,03  0   11,64461482 1,350252049 31  4,662488133 267,36
7   664802,83   5120137,97  0   8,040119106 0   15  0,31406122  0
8   663145,929  5118602,28  0   8,20656824  0   23  0,651391704 0
8   663806,037  5115087,15  0   19,83582055 0,348439127 22  12,18343538 384,98
14  662936,661  5113098,95  1,130733095 12,00008334 12,16962516 17  29,22692277 169,22
14  662385,647  5112502,6   0,96564664  15,34754887 5,447093834 24  0   687,09
12  664353,985  5110112,23  0   16,33680027 7,325945347 29  12,12448428 771,94
15  664489,723  5109450,36  9,026212203 14,25774618 1,005842738 28  8,199504891 622,77
21  666008,201  5114424,61  4,776382501 19,46280561 0   46  0   321,08
16  668731,333  5113994,17  1,752648429 13,46189499 2,525695809 59  9,012836502 105,69
12  673669,191  5117163,02  1,280555242 15,88511352 3,416913024 46  65,87803482 356,32
10  672124,789  5115978,86  0   11,89245635 0   50  0,466710926 75,24
9   670545,121  5114535,87  0   16,6675973  1,591922283 14  97,85829241 226,43
11  655410,906  5076167,76  1,587319162 3,948184091 0   25  0   9,02
8   658237,835  5087085,83  6,122725978 8,03795217  0   29  0   5,21
12  656026,012  5077108,7   0,304283198 13,23194576 2,342847094 30  1,443417751 488,66
6   661668,979  5087813,09  0   6,777864995 0   33  10,35774909 29,03
18  654752,781  5079706,23  0   17,852161   1,910107105 34  0,15005518  214,79
15  652009,008  5078389,62  1,5591955   17,99956839 0   32  6,782792698 433,66"
```

Many thanks!

Comment: haven't looked at this very closely, but: what's up with adding `Betas[1]` in your coef and std err calculations?  `X` should already include an intercept column ...

Comment: and ... can you simplify your model considerably?  Do you still get the same issue if you leave out the correlation model, include only a couple of predictors, etc. ?

Comment: I added Betas[1] because without it I obtained some weird plots...Using a lm it does work, but I think that also with a GLS should be possible obtain predictions...

Comment: I agree, but I still think you should be able to boil it down.  You can continue to use `gls`, just simplify things a bit.  Then it's much more likely that someone will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ben Bolker I removed one predictor (siepi) and also Betas1.
This seem to correct the problem on vcov matrix, but as you can see it seems that there are troubles on the intercept.
This is completely weird for me!

```
library(nlme)
library(MuMIn)
options(na.action=na.fail)


# Full model
rs_sin <- gls(Snlpall ~ marg + urban + crop + npatches + guyot, 
                        correlation=corGaus(form=~x_centroide+y_centroide),data=dati1, method="ML")

# Averaged model
dredge_rs_sin <- dredge(rs_sin,rank="AICc")
avg_rs_sin <- model.avg(get.models(dredge_rs_sin, subset=delta<2))

#Newdata
MyData <- data.frame(
Intercept=1,
marg=mean(dati1$marg,na.rm=TRUE),
urban=mean(dati1$urban,na.rm=TRUE),
crop=mean(dati1$crop,na.rm=TRUE),
npatches= seq(3,59,length=50),
guyot=mean(dati1$guyot,na.rm=TRUE))

X <- model.matrix (~npatches+crop+guyot+marg+urban,data=MyData)


#Plot for full model 

Betas <- coef(rs_sin)
FitManual <- X %*% Betas
SE <- sqrt(diag((X) %*% vcov(rs_sin)%*% t(X)))

plot(x=dati1$npatches,y=dati1$Snlpall,pch=16,
     xlab="",
     ylab="R") 
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual+1.96*SE,lty=3)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual-1.96*SE,lty=3)



# Plot for averaged model 

Betas1 <- coef(avg_rs_sin)
FitManual1 <- X %*% Betas
SE1 <- sqrt(diag((X) %*% vcov(avg_rs_sin)%*% t(X)))


plot(x=dati1$npatches,y=dati1$Snlpall,pch=16,
     xlab="npatches",
     ylab="R") 
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual1)
lines(x=MyData$npatches,y=FitManual1+1.96*SE1,lty=3)
lines(x=MyData$npathes,y=FitManual1-1.96*SE1,lty=3)
```